# Android invisible ListView item

Tags: android, listview, hide, listitem, invisible

I have `ListView` and I want hide some item, I use `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and it work well, but when `ListView` has many items and I scrolling then after several items again are invisible item.

Adapter:

```
public void setIndexHidenItem(int index){
    indexHidenItem = index;
}

public View getView(final int index, View view, ViewGroup group) {

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mainContext).inflate(R.layout.hlist_item_template, null);
    }
```

Change visibility:

```
if (indexHidenItem != -1){
        if (index == indexHidenItem){
            if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }else{
            if (view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

This is a traditional bug. You are using the ViewHolder pattern that reuse the same view for several listview items and you somehow get the view and change it's attribute and that will be reflected on every listview item that reuses this view again.

**Solution:**

You should record at your data store (ArrayList, HashMap, SparseArray, ....) of the Adapter that this view is invisible and calling Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() and in your Adapter's `getView()` you will need to check the visibility and change it upon that.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide item you should remember which item is invisible and in `getView()` method of your adapter you should check if current item should be visible or not and set visibility again. This is caused because your listview reuses its items, and `convertView` which is passing to your `getView()` method is actually one of your previously initialized items

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getItemViewType()` inside your adapter. [This example](http://kyogs.blogspot.com/2014/06/the-use-of-getviewtypecount-and.html) shows you how to use it. But instead of changing the view, you can just hide it. This way it wont show/hide views it shouldn't